# How does ENS (Ethereum Name System) work?

Tags: solidity

The reason of the ENS (Ethereum Name System): Making an address *0x123f681646d4a755815f9cb19e1acc8565a0dddd* reachable under a rememberable string like *abcdef.ghi.eth*.

But what I don't understand:

How is it built? It's not part of the original "Ethereum". So it's just a bunch of smart contracts that resolve *abcdef.ghi.eth* to its address.

But if I remember correctly: If I want to store an integer on the Ethereum blockchain, I need to allocate the space before I store a number...

So did the ENS-people just allocate a million address-String pairs? And if someone wants to set the entry (adress1 / foo.bar.eth), these values are stored in the next available allocated space??

Or is it possible to do this dynamically?

Answer (score 2):

You can look through the registry source [here](https://github.com/ensdomains/ens/blob/master/contracts/ENSRegistry.sol), but basically the allocation of records is done with `mapping (bytes32 => Record) records;` where Record stores the owner, resolver, and ttl. Mappings make it so consecutive data doesn't have to be allocated, instead the data is stored at the location in storage of the hash of the key.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand that correctly. When I create such a mapping `mapping (bytes32 => Record) records;` in my contract and if I add a Record with a transaction that is in block 4 and one more Record that is part of a transaction of block 5: The data/record will be stored in the blockchain. But where? As part of block 4 and 5 or as a part of the contract or how does that work?

Comment: Every block header contains the `stateRoot`, which is the root of the merkle tree of the global state after the transactions in that block are executed. At block 4, the state tree will contain just the entry you create in that block. At block 5, the state tree will contain both the records you added in 4 and 5.

Comment: This this image for more detail: https://i.stack.imgur.com/afWDt.jpg mainly the section labeled World State Trie